# how to enable command history of shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-history

I am using ubuntu 13.04, in this the command history of the shell is getting erased on close.

Can someone tell me how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: i have solved the issue.

the user i am logged into doesnot have the read/write permissions for .bash_history file so i changed the permissions and it worked.

Comment: @Kartik i cannot answer my own question until 8 hours from the time i created the question that's why i added it in the comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At a Bash prompt, type the following commands and do the steps listed after each one:

```
set -o | grep history
```

If you get "history off" then add this line at the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
set -o history
```

Next try:

```
echo $HISTFILE
echo $HISTSIZE
echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

If the first one is blank or `/dev/null`, add this line to the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history
```

If either of the last two print 0, set them to some number like the default of 500:

```
HISTFILESIZE=500
HISTSIZE=500
```

Do not forget to `source .bashrc` after saving `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible problem I just encountered is that your `.bash_history` file might be owned by root:

```
$ ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 root root 9558 Jun 21 21:56 /home/ubuntu/.bash_history
```

The solution is to `chown` it back to your user and group:

```
$ sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.bash_history
$ ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 9558 Jun 21 21:56 /home/ubuntu/.bash_history
```