# How to enable use of cursors to navigate commands in Linux Shell

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-history, cursor

I'm running a Docker container on Windows to enable me to work with Linux for some projects where that's required.  When using the CLI I'm unable to use the cursor keys to navigate the commands / the command history.  I'd expect pressing the up/down arrows to navigate through the previously run commands, and the left/right arrows to allow me to move the cursor to a part of the currently selected command to allow me to edit from that point.  Instead when I press the cursor keys I see the characters output to the console (i.e. up, down, left, right resolving to `^[[A`, `^[[B`, `^[[C`, and `^[[D` respectively).

Is there an option / install I'm missing to enable the expected behaviour?

I've seen information about [set -o](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85394/how-to-enable-command-history-of-shell); but I have no history entry:

```
# set -o | grep history
# set -o
Current option settings
errexit         off
noglob          off
ignoreeof       off
interactive     on
monitor         on
noexec          off
stdin           on
xtrace          off
verbose         off
vi              off
emacs           off
noclobber       off
allexport       off
notify          off
nounset         off
priv            off
nolog           off
debug           off
# set -o history
/bin/sh: 21: set: Illegal option -o history
```

The version of bash used is 4.4.20:

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the shell is actually `/bin/sh` not bash

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually using bash, though. The output is from `/bin/sh`, which could be something else like `dash`

Comment: Ah apologies; I'd wondered, but given `bash --version` gave me output I'd assumed I was using that shell (I'm still very new to Linux).  Thanks for the feedback.  Is there a command to tell you which shell you're in?

Comment: ps. The fix to my issue was to run the command `bash` - so as to put me into a bash shell; after which everything works as expected.  Sorry for the schoolboy error / thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per SteelDriver's comment, I'd misunderstood which shell I was in, as running `bash --version` had given output, I'd assumed I was within a bash shell.  In fact, I'd just called the exe with a command line parameter.  I'd been using `/bin/sh`.

The solution to enabling the expected cursor behavior was to switch to a shell which supported it; i.e. bash.  To do that; I just had to run the command: `bash`.

Per @StefanSkoglund's comment, to change things permanently, run `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

You can also list valid login shells via: `cat /etc/shells`.

You can see each users' default shell via: `cat /etc/passwd`; or better; `getent passwd`.

Comment: Do you want a permanent change ? If so change your login shell using chsh.

Comment: JohnLBevan getent passwd username  is faster especially if something like LDAP is used.